# Customize default Hibernate identity generation strategy for given type

Tags: hibernate

All our identity fields are `Long` and we don't like to pollute each Entity with `@GenericGenerator(strategy = "com.evil.MyStrategy")` or do the same with `hibernate.cfg`.

How can I customize defaults for `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` for `Long` type for given DB engine (Oracle and MySQL)?

Currently it requires adding conflicting annotations for Oracle and MySQL (impossible to keep single codebase with sequences for Oracle and `AUTO_INCREMENT` for MySQL).

**UPDATE** Similar question [How to make portable AND native ID generation in JPA 2 / Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216375/how-to-make-portable-and-native-id-generation-in-jpa-2-hibernate)